# Assembly: Syscall is being skipped

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, newline, carriage-return

I have the following assembly code down here. Basically I want to execute sys_write syscall twice to write something to stdout.

```
section     .text
global      _start

_start:

    ;write hello world
    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     edx, len_hello_world
    mov     ecx, hello_world
    int     0x80

    ;write my name
    mov    eax, 4
    mov    ebx, 1
    mov    edx, len_my_name
    mov    ecx, my_name
    int    0x80

    ;exit program
    mov     eax, 1    ; sys_exit
    int     0x80

section     .data

    hello_world         db  "Hello, World!", 0xd
    len_hello_world     equ $ - hello_world
    my_name             db  " My name is Moritz!", 0x13
    len_my_name         equ $ - my_name
```

Expected output:

```
Hello, World! My name is Moritz!
```

Actual output:

```
My name is Moritz!
```

My question is: Why is the first sys_call "skipped" (sorry for layman terms, i'm total noob)

Comment: It isn't skipped. `0xd` is carriage return meaning go back to start of the line. The other string is then printed over it. It's unclear why you put it there since your expected output is all on a single line. Delete it.

Comment: And change 0x13 to 0x0A, which is the right character to "print" a line feed.

Comment: `0x13` is "device control 3" in ASCII. You probably meant decimal 13, which is 0xd, a carriage return. But as others have said, 0xd isn't the correct control to use for ending the line anyway.

Comment: @Jester my goal was to execute sys_write syscall twice and print two individual strings. I adjusted my code according to the comments here, and now finally it works as expected. Thank you all for your help!